# PHP include not showing up

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes

I've got a php include, with a path going to `[root]/Edge-animations/splash/publish/web/splash.php`, a valid path on my server. On my first attempt, I got an error saying that the path is invalid; it turned out that I need to put the complete server path (along the lines of `/homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/Edge-animations/splash/publish/web/splash.php`). After correcting the link, I tried reloading my page; it didn't show an error, but it didn't show the file it was supposed to include, either. My PHP syntax is as follows:

```
<?php include('/homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/Edge-animations/splash/publish/web/splash.php'); ?>
```

And matches the syntax I used for a working PHP include on another page. What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*
The included file is an HTML file outputted by Edge; I changed the extension from .html to .php. Here's its code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=IE8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-          frame/1/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="splash-v1_edgePreload.js">    </script>
    <style>
    .edgeLoad-Splash { display:none; }
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage" class="Splash">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also now added parentheses and a semicolon to the link; it still doesn't work.

Comment: What level of `error_reporting` do you have set?

Comment: You may have a problem in the included file. Something could be aborting the script, altering the error_settings to hide errors, ect. Show us the code of this included file.

Comment: i think you are missing a ";" at the end ...the syntax should be <?php include 'filename'; ?>

Comment: I've added the ";", and now the server returns an error saying that the file's not found under `/homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/splash.php` . It seems to be treating the _folder_ "splash" as a PHP file, for some reason.
Here's the complete error transcript:

<br>

`Warning: include(/homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/splash/publish/web/splash-v1.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/splash.php on line 163`

For the record, line 163 of my document contains the include code.

Comment: @Verandaguy check that file exists using if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
   include('pages/'.$page.'.php');
}

Comment: I've never used file_exists. Do I replace "$page" with just the file name, or the path to the file?

Comment: Use relative path (with `./` or `../` at beginning)

Comment: @Verandaguy full pathname to the file http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I'm taking a look at @Sibu's link, but I'm also trying a relative path.

Comment: I've tried using relative links (both ./ and ../), but neither seems to work. It keeps looking for the file I'm trying to include, inside the file I'm currently working on (which is called splash.php).

Comment: I've determined, using if file-exists, that the valid path is, in this case, `/kunden/homepages/3/d426847376/htdocs/Edge-animations/splash/publish/web/splash-v1.php`.</ br>
I've changed the include so as to link to that file, but now it doesn't display anything. Is it possible that that's due to the fact that the Edge output HTML links to a JS file, which it subsequently runs?

Comment: @Verandaguy i guess you are using wrong pathname, another method would be <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Edge-animations/splash/publish/web/anotherfile.php"); ?> and instead use a dummy file and see if it is getting included

Comment: It seems to work flawlessly with a dummy .htm file I made; no luck with the Edge exported file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for testing purposes try

```
<?php
$path = '/homepages/3/..........';
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo 'path=',$path, "<br />\n";
if ( !file_exists($path) ) {
    die('no such file');
}
else {
    //include $path;
    echo '<p>opening file</p>';
    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
    if ( !$fp ) {
        die('open failed');
    }
    echo '<p>reading file</p>';
    $content = stream_get_contents($fp);
    if ( false===$content ) {
        die('read failed');
    }
    echo '<p>strlen(content)=',strlen($content), '<p>';
}
```